# I tried to mount a volume from windows via terminal, it showed that the mount point I specified was not a block device

Tags: mount

Here is what I did.

I gave the command in the terminal

```
mount /home/myfolder/mounting_folder /dev/sda3
```

It displayed a message that

```
mount: /home/myfolder/mounting_folder is not a block device
```

Why isn't this working?

Comment: try it the other way around, linux command work often with `command source destination` here you want to mount your source to your destination directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't working because you're trying to mount the target on the device (not the other way around like you're supposed to). Simply swap the arguments:

```
mount /dev/sda3 /home/myfolder/mounting_folder
```